# How to make field required in kotlin DSL builders

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, when creating a custom DSL, what is the best way to force filling **required fields** inside the builder's extension functions in compile time. E.g.:

```
person {
    name = "John Doe" // this field needs to be set always, or compile error
    age = 25
}
```

One way to force it is to set value in a function parameter instead of the body of the extension function.

```
person(name = "John Doe") {
    age = 25
}
```

but that makes it a bit more unreadable if there are more required fields.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 16):

[New type inference](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/06/kotlin-1-3-40-released/) enables you to make a null-safe compile-time checked builder:

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int?)

// Create a sealed builder class with all the properties that have default values
sealed class PersonBuilder {
    var age: Int? = null // `null` can be a default value if the corresponding property of the data class is nullable

    // For each property without default value create an interface with this property
    interface Named {
        var name: String
    }

    // Create a single private subclass of the sealed class
    // Make this subclass implement all the interfaces corresponding to required properties
    private class Impl : PersonBuilder(), Named {
        override lateinit var name: String // implement required properties with `lateinit` keyword
    }

    companion object {
        // Create a companion object function that returns new instance of the builder
        operator fun invoke(): PersonBuilder = Impl()
    }
}

// For each required property create an extension setter
fun PersonBuilder.name(name: String) {
    contract {
        // In the setter contract specify that after setter invocation the builder can be smart-casted to the corresponding interface type
        returns() implies (this@name is PersonBuilder.Named)
    }
    // To set the property, you need to cast the builder to the type of the interface corresponding to the property
    // The cast is safe since the only subclass of `sealed class PersonBuilder` implements all such interfaces
    (this as PersonBuilder.Named).name = name
}

// Create an extension build function that can only be called on builders that can be smart-casted to all the interfaces corresponding to required properties
// If you forget to put any of these interface into where-clause compiler won't allow you to use corresponding property in the function body
fun <S> S.build(): Person where S : PersonBuilder, S : PersonBuilder.Named = Person(name, age)
```

Use case:

```
val builder = PersonBuilder() // creation of the builder via `invoke` operator looks like constructor call
builder.age = 25
// builder.build() // doesn't compile because of the receiver type mismatch (builder can't be smart-casted to `PersonBuilder.Named`)
builder.name("John Doe")
val john = builder.build() // compiles (builder is smart-casted to `PersonBuilder & PersonBuilder.Named`)
```

Now you can add a DSL function:

```
// Caller must call build() on the last line of the lambda
fun person(init: PersonBuilder.() -> Person) = PersonBuilder().init()
```

DSL use case:

```
person {
    name("John Doe") // will not compile without this line
    age = 25
    build()
}
```

---

Finally, on JetBrains open day 2019 it was said that the Kotlin team researched contracts and tried to implement contracts that will allow creating safe DSL with required fields. [Here](https://youtu.be/g0ivd1TMu9s?t=1579) is a talk recording in Russian. This feature isn't even an experimental one, so
maybe it will never be added to the language.

Comment: Quite a lot of boilerplate code is required to achieve this, so I hope the contracts will mature to be put into action. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it's quite clever and interesting. A pity it's so verbose. My main issue is that you usually wouldn't need to call `build()` from within a DSL, and I couldn't find a way to enforce the contracts elsewhere without forcing users of the DSL to do it themselves. Any suggestions?

Comment: @fast3r, unfortunately, as far as I can tell, you can't enforce contracts without forcing DSL users to either call some function at the end of the lambda or explicitly return `this` from the lambda.

Comment: I worked around it by adding the type checks and smart casts in the extension function of the "last" field in the DSL (in the example case, `age`). Not ideal but still a bit more good looking for the DSL users, if you don't mind forcing that field to always be specified as last.

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: @elect, not that I’m aware of.

Answer (score 5):

In case you're developing for Android I wrote a lightweight linter to verify mandatory DSL attributes.

To solve your use case you will only need to add an annotation `@DSLMandatory` to your `name` property setter and the linter will catch any place when it is not assigned and display an error:

```
@set:DSLMandatory
var name: String
```

[image: err]

You can take a look here:
https://github.com/hananrh/dslint/

Answer (score 0):

Simple, throw an exception if it's not defined in your DLS after the block

```
fun person(block: (Person) -> Unit): Person {
val p = Person()
block(p)
if (p.name == null) {
  // throw some exception
}
return p
}
```

Or if you want to enforce it at build time, just make it return something useless to the outer block if not defined, like null.

```
fun person(block: (Person) -> Unit): Person? {
val p = Person()
block(p)
if (p.name == null) {
  return null
}
return p
}
```

I'm guessing your going off [this example](https://proandroiddev.com/writing-dsls-in-kotlin-part-1-7f5d2193f277) so maybe address would be the better example case:

```
fun Person.address(block: Address.() -> Unit) {
// city is required
var tempAddress = Address().apply(block)
if (tempAddress.city == null) {
   // throw here
}
}
```

But what if we wanted to ensure everything was defined, but also wanted to let you do it in any order **and** break at compile time. Simple, have two types!

```
data class Person(var name: String = null,
              var age: Int = null,
              var address: Address = null)
data class PersonBuilder(var name: String? = null,
              var age: Int? = null,
              var address: Address? = null)
fun person(block: (PersonBuilder) -> Unit): Person {
    val pb = PersonBuilder()
    block(p)
    val p = Person(pb.name, pb.age, pb.address)
    return p
}
```

This way, you get to you the non-strict type to build, but it better be null-less by the end. This was a fun question, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, non of these force it in compile time which was my goal. I like required fields to not be nullable. In the last example, put the Person's name as not-nullable type and you will see the problem. The DSL wouldn't force setting the name in the builder and only solution is throwing runtime exception.

Comment: Yeah, you're correct, every case depends on runtime checks unfortunately, I was mistaken on the one case. I really don't have a better option than what I proposed unfortunately.

Comment: My best idea at the moment is to include a static analysis component with the DSL to throw an error. I do not believe Kotlin supports a compile time error here.

Comment: I believe so too. Unless it can be done with kotlin contracts, but not sure how advanced the uses are.